# Print a part of a string of variable length

Tags: python, micropython

I would like to print the IP1 adress in the string `request`; these are the contents of said string:

```
b'GET /submit_IP?IP1=192.168.15.66&IP2=255.255.255.0&IP3=192.168.15.1&IP4=192.168.15.1 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 192.168.15.66\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nUpgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9\r\nReferer: http://192.168.15.66/submit_IP?IP1=192.168.15.66&IP2=255.255.255.0&IP3=192.168.15.1&IP4=192.168.15.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept-Language: en,cs;q=0.9,en-GB;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7\r\n\r\n'
```

However, the problem is that the adress can be longer or shorter, such as `1.1.1.1` or `192.168.150.150`. I tried:

```
print(request[(request.find(IP1=) + 4):-(len(request) - (len(request) - request.find(IP2=) - 2))])
```

... which returns **SyntaxError: invalid syntax**.

Comment: Your _SyntaxError_ comes from the missing "" around your keywords. This does not mean you will receive the correct result by fixing it. But it gives you the chance to work it out by yourself.

Comment: Ooooh... damn, blind me, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
request = b'GET /submit_IP?IP1=192.168.15.66&IP2=255.255.255.0&IP3=192.168.15.1&IP4=192.168.15.1 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 192.168.15.66\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nUpgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9\r\nReferer: http://192.168.15.66/submit_IP?IP1=192.168.15.66&IP2=255.255.255.0&IP3=192.168.15.1&IP4=192.168.15.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept-Language: en,cs;q=0.9,en-GB;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7\r\n\r\n'

startint = str(request).find('IP1=') + 4
endint = str(request).find('&IP2=')

print(str(request)[startint:endint])
```

Output:

```
192.168.15.66
```

EDIT: one-liner

```
print(str(request)[str(request).find('IP1=') + 4:str(request).find('&IP2=')])
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any change this could be squeezed into one line?

Comment: Sure, let me edit that real quick. I did not write it as a one liner as usually they obscure readability.

Answer (score 1):

Using Regex:

**Ex:**

```
import re

s = b'GET /submit_IP?IP1=192.168.15.66&IP2=255.255.255.0&IP3=192.168.15.1&IP4=192.168.15.1 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 192.168.15.66\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nUpgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9\r\nReferer: http://192.168.15.66/submit_IP?IP1=192.168.15.66&IP2=255.255.255.0&IP3=192.168.15.1&IP4=192.168.15.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept-Language: en,cs;q=0.9,en-GB;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7\r\n\r\n'
m = re.search(r"IP1=(.+?)(?=&)", str(s))
if m:
    print(m.group(1))    #--> 192.168.15.66
```

Comment: Ah, thanks, but sadly I'm in micropython, so I believe I can't import this module...

Comment: @aanonym Use `ure` http://docs.micropython.org/en/v1.9.3/pyboard/library/ure.html

Answer (score 1):

I would use a more general approach that decodes the entire query string using the python library [urllib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) and then get the parameter you want, as follows:

```
import urllib.parse
query_string = request.split(b" ", 2)[1].split(b"?", 1)[1]
parameters = urllib.parse.parse_qs(query_string)

print(parameters[b"IP1"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could search your `request` string for the characters `=` and `&` to find their positions.

```
print(request[request.find("=")+1:request.find("&")])
```

Comment: Cool. Why almost? May be you want to upvote my answer?

Comment: I would if it works. The input string is a byte literal, so your code will throw an error on the search strings. One way of dealing with this is to first convert `request` to a string, like I did in my answer. There are more ways that lead to Rome, though